# neural netork loss function for hierarchical classification

Tags: classification, conv-neural-network, loss-functions

I am trying to use a convolution neural network to classify organisms into the correct phylum. It's easy enough to just treat this as a classification problem and train on some images of animals (there are about 35 phyla for animals). The problem is that in case of an incorrect classification some answers are more wrong than others. different phyla come from different kingdoms which come from different domains. So the questions is how do I approach this classification problem with the added constraint that if a classification is incorrect it more than likely chooses a closely related phylum? I have looked for loss functions (my initial hunch) and found some technical research articles but so far no established approach.