# Loss function for NN classification with subclasses

Tags: neural-networks, classification, loss-functions

There is a similar question asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319209/neural-netork-loss-function-for-hierarchical-classification) but with no answers.

In short, I have a few classes, each separated into another few subclasses. E.g. `[BMW, Honda, Toyota, Boeing, Airbus]`. If the correct answer is `[BMW]`, obviously predicting another car would be more correct than predicting a plane.

So perhaps, instead of target = `[1 0 0 0 0]`, I would rather have it to be `[0.8 0.1 0.1 0 0]`. Initially, I was thinking about `Cross Entropy Loss`, but Pytorch would only allow 1 label to be a hardcoded `[1]`. And after more thinking, I am not even sure if this would work.

It would also be much preferable if there is a native Pytorch function that does this.

Comment: Which PyTorch function are you using? Please add this to your question.

Comment: @mhdadk I plan to use `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` as I said, but I believe `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` does not support custom probabilities `Target: (N) where each value is 0 ≤ targets[i] ≤ C−1`. So, I do not have a fully implemented model now.

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable. You can implement a custom loss function.